# How to install gdb on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, gdb

How do I install the GNU Debugger (gdb) on Arch Linux? I've checked that I don't already have gdb installed by running this command:

```
gdb -help
```

I've tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install gdb
```

but it's not working.

Comment: -1 because the question doesn't show research effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arch Linux uses different package management. Use the below command format.

```
pacman -S package_name1 package_name2
```

Or run `man pacman` to learn more about pacman.

Reference: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman

Comment: and which package is gdb?